# Where should the animation be done?

Tags: animation, unity

Let's say I want to make a character (an animal) with a stick in its mouth.

I dont understand if the animation (done in Blender) should have the stick in its mouth or if it should be done in Unity/Shiva, etc.

Is there any place where I can read the theory behind it? How shall I do interaction between two objects like an animal eating something?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know where you could go to read about it, but the best way to go if you don't intend for the dog to always have the stick in its mouth is to make the stick a separate object, animate the dog as if the stick were in the mouth, and along with the dog have a "locator" for where the stick should be (including its orientation) as the animation progresses.

It's ok to put the stick in the dog's mouth while you export it, but only if you can do it in such a way that they remain two separate objects for the export.  E.g. in Maya you would reference in the stick, and then your exporter would know not to export referenced geometry.

Comment: I don't understand from this answer if the animation is done in Unity or in Blender. Can you clarify?

Comment: @ashes999 you author the animation in an authoring tool (e.g. Blender) and play it back in your game engine (e.g. Unity).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to create an EMPTY in blender, that when Unity Imports the .blend file considers a separate object at the position of your EMPTY.

From there, I would assign the world/global-space location to the stick via "Transform.position" of the EMPTY, of which you could also create separately in Unity itself.

As long as you're using "Transform.position" in your code, your stick should always be able to position itself at the point of the empty(if you place it in your "public void Update" code section).